# How to align components within p:selectOneMenu

Tags: css, primefaces, alignment

I am trying to make the "components" of a PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu right aligned to fit the general look and feel of a form.

It works for the selectItems but the selected one has some kind of offset
is there a way to fix this besides hardcoding the position in px?

[image]

The following is the code for one row within a form
and the css I added to get the values right aligned
by adding the css the values are in fact aligned to the right of the SelectOneMenu but like you can see in the picture the selected value has a big margin on the right side

```
<p:column style="vertical-align:top;padding-top:8px">
    <p:panelGrid id="tdkDetailsPanel" styleClass="hardwareDetailsPanel" columns="2">
<h:outputLabel value="Item: " />
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{backingBean.selectedItemId}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.availableItemIds}" />
  <p:ajax update="itemDetailsPanel" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<!-- more of the same -->
</p:panelGrid>
</p:column>
```

---

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: right !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel {
    text-align: right !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-list-item {
    text-align: right !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-label {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

Comment: create a JSfiddle example or post your code here

Comment: There is only 1 component visible, so Align with what? And Most of it normally **is** aligned, so the fact that it is not might be caused by custom css. [mcve]  please and this is most likely a html/css issue, not a jsf one (so removed the jsf tag)

Comment: I want the text inside the SelectOneMenu to be on the right side of the SelectoneMenu. I will add a code example more specific the css I used shortly

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using

```
<h:selectonemenu>
```

instead of

```
<p:selectonemenu>
```

adding the text-align property to this gave me the desired result

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I alsy tried this combination but it also had this offset shown in the picture

Comment: Then I guess it's some other css that overrides this one. You should check in developer tools which class is being used.

Comment: thats probably it but since I already "fixed" it by using the other SelectOneMenu I cant justify searching the css that causes this behavior at the moment